# How to access Spark UI on EMR?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, emr

I launched a EMR Spark cluster with 2 machines in interactive mode.

with config sets:

```
cluster manager: yarn-client
bootstrap: no
IAM: all
```

and then open all the TCP ports of master to ANYWHERE.

there is nothing at master:4040

where/how can I find the Spark UI in this case ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31493538/4394783

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spark UI on AWS EMR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460079/spark-ui-on-aws-emr)

Comment: Also, Hadoop and associated software isn't built for Internet exposure, be sure to lock your master back down.